# Small numbers misrepresented in windows

Tags: windows, model, fortran, numbers, exe

I am running a model which is written in Fortan (an executable), in some runs it started to deliver constant errors and apparently incoherent results, however when I closely checked the results file (a text with n columns of data) and I realized that when the concentration of certain mineral is very very low, lets say **2.9984199E-306**, the code omits the 'E' and the number presented is **2.9984199-306** which of course causes problems. Since I have no access to the source code of the executable file, is there a way to avoid this problem in Windows? I have seen that in other computers these numbers are directly replaced by zero, however I was not able to find the specific configuration to achieve it.

Comment: You can correct your processing steps to read those valid numbers, but we can't make suggestions unless you show more detail of them. Perhaps there are runtime options your program/compiler runtime has to round small numbers to zero, but again we need more detail.

Answer (score 0):

You will need access to code to change the output formatting or you will need to post-process your output.  You are seeing standard conforming Fortran behavior.  Consider the simple program

```
program foo
  implicit none
  real(8) x
  integer i
  x = 1
  do i = 1, 10
     x = x / 5.4321e11
     write(*,'(ES15.7)') x
  end do
end program foo
```

It's output is

```
1.8409086E-12
3.3889446E-24
6.2387373E-36
1.1484945E-47
2.1142735E-59
3.8921843E-71
7.1651557E-83
1.3190397E-94
2.4282316-106
4.4701525-118
```

See Fortran 2018 Standard, 13.7.2.3.3 E and D editing, in particular, Table 13.1.